# Compilation error using TFHpple framework from Swift

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, swift

I have this HTML,

```
 <div class="header1" style="text-align: center;">


 <div class="s">
          <center>
                  <table>
       <tr>
                          <td>
                     <ul style="position: relative;">
                       <li>
                    <a>
         <p>
   Apple Kid

        </p>
```

and I want to get the the word "Apple kid"  as an output using  Swift.

I used the TFHpple Framework for this, but after adding all the necessary things it showing an error. Like in the Objective-C file

```
the  XPathQuery.h
//
//  XPathQuery.h
//  FuelFinder
//
//  Created by Matt Gallagher on 4/08/08.
//  Copyright 2008 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

NSArray *PerformHTMLXPathQuery(NSData *document, NSString *query);
NSArray *PerformHTMLXPathQueryWithEncoding(NSData *document, NSString *query,NSString *encoding);
NSArray *PerformXMLXPathQuery(NSData *document, NSString *query);
NSArray *PerformXMLXPathQueryWithEncoding(NSData *document, NSString *query,NSString *encoding);
```

It showing an error at these functions about Unknown type.

The XpathQuery.m

```
//
//  XPathQuery.m
//  FuelFinder
//
//  Created by Matt Gallagher on 4/08/08.
//  Copyright 2008 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "XPathQuery.h"

#import <libxml/tree.h>
#import <libxml/parser.h>
#import <libxml/HTMLparser.h>
#import <libxml/xpath.h>
#import <libxml/xpathInternals.h>

NSDictionary *DictionaryForNode(xmlNodePtr currentNode, NSMutableDictionary *parentResult,BOOL parentContent);
NSArray *PerformXPathQuery(xmlDocPtr doc, NSString *query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should share the precise errors you received, but I had no problems using TFHpple from Swift. As you do with Objective-C, you have to

- make sure you link to the `libxml` library in your build phases
- add `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` to your header search paths in the build settings

See the installation instructions on Wenderlich's [How To Parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) or Cocoa with Love's [Using libxml2 for XML parsing and XPath queries in Cocoa](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html).

When you add the TFHpple source to your project, you should be prompted to create a bridging header. Do so, and then add `#import "TFHpple"` to it. For more information, see the *Importing Objective-C into Swift* section of the [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_77) chapter of the *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C* guide.

Once you do that, you should be able to use TFHpple without incident from Swift.