# Importing TFHpple on Swift

Tags: swift

I'm relatively new to programming and I have spent hours on trying to understand how to import TFHpple library (or any Objective C library) into my Swift code. I have read the documentations but I still don't really understand it can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Objective C code from Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237238/compilation-error-using-tfhpple-framework-from-swift/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add the [Objective-C files](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple/tree/master/Pod/Classes) to your project
2. Xcode will ask if you want a Bridging Header, say **YES**
3. Add `#import "TFHpple.h"` to your bridging header
4. Add `libxml2` to Build Phases > Link binary with library
5. Add `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` in Header Search Paths
6. Call your methods in Swift

Comment: Don't forget libxml2 and header path changes, too.

Comment: I also had to add `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` to the top of XPathQuery.h.