# How would I request text from a Website in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

So I am making an iOS app, and I making a Alert Bar that updates each time the app is opened depending what text is on a website. But when I make my HTTP request it only gives me the HTML of that website. How would I get text from the web page instead of the HTML?

I'm using Swift 
Code Below

```
let url = NSURL(string: "www.examlpewebsite.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, text, error) in
    self.alertLabel.text = (NSString(data: text, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

So how would this be done?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What text are you looking for?  Something embedded in the HTML that you're getting or something from a different URL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626984/convert-html-string-to-something-useful-in-swift

Comment: @PhillipMills Like if I had a text box on the site I would want to retrieve the text in that text box, how would this be done?

Comment: @ThomasKilian How do you use the NSScanner?

Comment: Just click the link in the post. It's all in the docu and it's not too difficult.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Yes but I'm using Swift.

Comment: Hu. If you wanna code Cocoa you need to understand at least the basics of Obj-C (that is how to translate a signature into Swift). The linked page is Apple's docu as is.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Sorry, i'm decently new at Swift. :)

Comment: So now you know. Try looking into other docs (like NSView) where Apple already provides both Obj-C and Swift signatures. You should get the idea, I guess. For sure you can't learn it at SO. This is no tutorial place here.

Comment: @ThomasKilian k thanks anyway dude ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How could I request text from a Website In Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572228/how-could-i-request-text-from-a-website-in-swift)

Answer (score 2):

Your technique of retrieving the response from the web server is fine. The question is how to parse the response.
There are two approaches:

1. Retrieve the HTML from web server and use a HTML parser, like [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple), to parse it. See http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios.
2. Create a web page on the web server that returns JSON or something like that. This can then be retrieved and parsed using `NSJSONSerialization`.

The latter approach is preferable (it's a robust way to get information from a web server). The former is fine if you're really stuck parsing HTML.

Comment: This looks what I might need but I need it for Swift.

Comment: I'm not sure which approach you're talking about, but both work with Swift fine. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28262924/1271826 re TFHpple. (If you see people advising NDHpple for Swift, I'd personally advise sticking with TFHpple. I don't think NDHpple is as mature.) `NSJSONSerialization` also works seamlessly in Swift.