# How could I request text from a Website In Swift?

Tags: swift

So I am making an iOS app, and I making a Alert Bar that updates each time the app is opened depending what text is on a website. But when I make my HTTP request it only gives me the HTML of that website. How would I get text from the web page instead of the HTML?

I'm using Swift Code Below

```
let url = NSURL(string: "www.examlpewebsite.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, text, error) in
    self.alertLabel.text = (NSString(data: text, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

So how would this be done?

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for ages so if this could be solved that would be amazing!

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a XML/HTTP parser like the [Swift-HTML-Parser](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Swift-HTML-Parser). Just check the 'Usage' information on the github repository. It shows how to add the files to your project. Then, you can use the framework to parse the html:

```
//your HTML
let html = (NSString(data: text, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

var err : NSError?
var parser     = HTMLParser(html: html, error: &err)
if err != nil {
    println(err)
    exit(1)
}

var bodyNode   = parser.body

//Add tags to search
if let inputNodes = bodyNode?.findChildTags("b") {
    for node in inputNodes {
        println(node.contents)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Christian_Worez This looks interesting but I would rather do it without an extension, any generic swift way to do this?

Comment: Not a Swift way, but most of the frameworks use libxml2. So you could make it by creating an own framework. But I would recommend you to use one of the existing frameworks. It will save you a lot of coding time which you could use for other things. :)

Comment: Do I give  HTMLParser.swift, HTMLNode.swift, and Swift-HTML-Parser-Bridging-Header.h their own classes? btw thanks for answering my question. ;)

Comment: Yes. Just drag n' drop them into your project and follow the instructions.

Comment: @Christian_Worez I found the Objective-C Bridging Header Setting but I don't see how I add the Swift-HTML-Parser-Bridging-Header.h to it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your website you can save yourself a lot of trouble by providing a version of the request that delivers just the text. Most web frameworks allow you to provide whatever format you desire and if you choose a URL that provides e.g. `text/plain` you may directly use the body of the answer. To do that you would probably implement a request which you could access as

```
let url = NSURL(string: "www.examlpewebsite.com/message.txt")
```

which would set the response header `Content-Type: text/plain` to indicate that it delivers "just the text". This will then save you the effort of parsing the answer. Please post your favorite web framework or search for an answer which provides the above, I am sure you will find something.

Comment: It is my Website but I don't know much of anything about web frameworks :(